# VSCode and C environment

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I'm sorry for my English
It can work on DEV C++, but VSCode ? environment is not change
When i run hello world on VSCode it will  appear something like that

```
(The task provider for "C/C++" tasks unexpectedly provided a task of type "shell".)
```

And this is my Json file:
1,Launch.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMikP.png)

2,task.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEnef.png)

3,cppconfig
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoOr7.png)

I try something for my question 
1,win10 environment
But it is correct
2,vscode extension
I use some version,but...
3,vscode
I try some old version,but...

Comment: Please [edit] and post your config/json files as **text**. Highlight the code blocks and click on the `{ }` button to format it correctly. This will help people copy the code into their own IDE and help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `"type" = "shell"` given in your second image (task.json) is causing the error to come. **It's a bug newly come in VSCode** (I realized after reading its official GitHub [article](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5388#issuecomment-625275433).

The way to fix the issue is to downgrade C/C++ Insiders to 0.27.1. Just search it and download.